# Compiled some simple swift code, but I can't execute it on other machine

Tags: swift, macos, compilation, binary

Like I said in the title, I wrote some very simple swift code, no other 3rd party library used, only import `Foundation`. I compiled the code with `swiftc` to a binary executable file. I can execute it by just using the file name of the binary. Then copy it to iCloud and eventually download it onto other machine. 
I just can't make it run on other machine. 
I checked the swift version is exactly same. 
Error message showing like below:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/helloworld
>     Reason: image not found

This is just a common error complaining swift runtime environment. 
But I just don't understand why since the swift version is exactly same on both machines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing a couple of things:

First, delete the derived data (File -> Workplace Settings -> click the arrow next the folder path -> send everything in that folder to trash.

Then do a clean of the project (shift + command + k) and rebuild (command + b).

And another thing to check is that `Always embed Swift Standard Libraries` is set to Yes

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like the OP is using Xcode for compiling, but just compiling with `swiftc`.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to tell what is wrong without seeing your code, and i tried but could not reproduced your problem.
Here is what i tried to do:

Created test.swift and added the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

print("hello world")
```

Compiled it into a executable by running:

```
swiftc test.swift -o test
```

Copied it to another machine and made it executable:

```
chmod +x test
```

Executed

```
test
```

And it pirnted

```
hello world
```

Check your swift version:

```
swift --version
```

Both of my machine's swift version is

> Apple Swift version 4.0.3 (swiftlang-900.0.74.1 clang-900.0.39.2)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9